# What are the different ways of static and dynamic linking in cmake projects?

Tags: cmake, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am supposed to write a small application to identify dependencies in cmake projects and group them by static or dynamic linkage. I'm not an expert in static and dynamic linking, but I don't have to get something running correctly, I just need to find out, how they are linked.

For that I looked for an overview of the different ways to link a dependency. Unfortunately I failed, but found found a lot of different (and sometimes confusing) ways on multiple pages.

So, here is what I found out yet. It would be great if you could comment on it and maybe add further ways I missed. If I misunderstood something in general, please let me know :)

**Dynamic linking**

*in code*

- `LoadLibraray("foo.dll")`

*in CMakeLists.txt*

- `option (BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY ON)` - this means, the default behaviour is dynamic linking?
- `add_library(foo SHARED bar)`
- `target_link_libraries(foo bar[.so/.dll])` - using shared library means dynamic linking?

**Static linking**

*in CMakeLists.txt*

- `option (BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY OFF)` - this means, the default behaviour is static linking?
- `add_library(foo STATIC bar)`
- `target_link_libraries(foo bar[.a/.lib])` - using static library means static linking?

As far as I understood, evaluating these lines of code enables me to find statically linked dependencies on the one hand and dynamically linked dependencies on the other hand. Is that correct?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Often on Windows you will need to link both a `.lib` and a `.dll` so linking to a `.lib` does not rule out dynamic linkage.

Comment: Ok, but if I am able to identify lib and dll files belonging to the same dependency, I could identify the linkage of that dependency. Can I say that? However, in those situations, has the dependency both files which are linked statically and those which are linked dynamically? Or does it mean, that a dependency with lib and dll files is linked dynamically at all?